# VB6 IDE performs too slowly on Windows 7 machine

Tags: windows-7

I am running Windows 7 x64, and have installed Visual Basic 6.

This is a very fast machine, however, VB6 IDE runs too slow.

The forms designer is very slow especially when moving form controls (textboxes, buttons etc.) to different areas of the screen.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: and what about projects i have developed in vb6 few years ago? i am supposed to maintain them. and as far as i know, there is no easy way to upgrade them to .NET , other than starting from stretch

Comment: Don't know if this is feasible, but maybe it would run faster in a winXP VM on the win7 box. I had to do this for some old code that has to build in VC6.

Comment: Are the best/appropriate video drivers being used?

Comment: but thats more of a hassle. isn't it?

Comment: @p.campbell yes man, all drivers are perfectly installed

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can try by going to vb.exe properties, click Compatibility tab, Now select this option "Disable Desktop Composition".. This should resolve your problem